# When should I use dropdown or sheets in mobile design?

Tags: mobile-web, dropdown

I'm working on a web app design, and I'm designing for both mobile and desktop devices. In desktop forms, I'm using normal dropdown selection lists (or dropdowns) and in mobile I'm uncertain if I should use dropdowns as well or sheets, like the ones presented in Material Design: https://m2.material.io/components/sheets-bottom

Is there a rule? When should I use one or the other?

Comment: I dont think sheets are appropriate for select lists in forms. Sheets are anchored to the bottom, out of sequence of the form. And they provide peripheral support, not inherent to the primary task.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom sheets would not be the correct component to use in forms.

How many options are within the select input? If less than 7 it's usually better practice to use checkboxes or radio buttons. 7 being the number of options memorable in short term memory.

[UX planet article on Medium about human memory for UX](https://uxplanet.org/how-human-memory-works-tips-for-ux-designers-12b14071bdf9)

If there are many options the standard select dropdown is still usable. You could also break the form into steps on mobile so that the "select input" step removes the need for any dropdown. You can show the full list on the page removing an action to open the list, once an option is selected it can move onto the next step automatically. I'd also suggest including a confirmation step at the end with all of the answers in 1 view if going down the stepped route. This removes any anxiety from the user as they can confirm it is all correct.

Hope that helps!